# How to create a named object from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const field = ['name', 'address']

const data = field.map(item => {
  return {item: {mode: 'insensitive', sort: 'desc'}}
})
```

the variable data above is

```
[
 {
  item: {
   mode: 'insensitive', 
   sort: 'desc'
  },
  item: {
   mode: 'insensitive', 
   sort: 'desc'
  }
 }
]
```

I want the value to be

```
[
 {
  name: {
   mode: 'insensitive', 
   sort: 'desc'
  },
  address: {
   mode: 'insensitive', 
   sort: 'desc'
  }
 }
]
```

is that possible? or any method to do it better, thank's for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by wrapping your `item` object around brackets `[]`

```
const data = field.map(item => {
    return {[item]: {mode: 'insensitive', sort: 'desc'}}
})
```

Output:

```
[
  { name: { mode: 'insensitive', sort: 'desc' } },
  { address: { mode: 'insensitive', sort: 'desc' } }
]
```

You can alternatively also use `arrow` functions to make your code look cleaner, You can learn more about arrow functions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
const field = ['name', 'address']
const data = field.map(item => ({[item]: {mode: 'insensitive', sort: 'desc'}}));
console.log(data)
```